# Equality for GADTs which erase type parameter

Tags: haskell, gadt

I cannot implement an instance of `Eq` for the following typesafe DSL for expressions implemented with GADTs.

```
data Expr a where
  Num :: Int -> Expr Int
  Bool :: Bool -> Expr Bool
  Plus :: Expr Int -> Expr Int -> Expr Int
  If :: Expr Bool -> Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr a
  Equal :: Eq a => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool
```

Expressions can be either of type `Bool` or `Int`. There are constructors for literals `Bool` and `Num` which have the corresponding types. Only `Int` expressions can be added up (constructor `Plus`). The condition in the `If` expression should have type `Bool` while both branches should have the same type. There is also an equality expression `Equal` whose operands should have the same type, and the type of the equality expression is `Bool`.

I have no problems implementing the interpreter `eval` for this DSL. It compiles and works like a charm:

```
eval :: Expr a -> a
eval (Num x) = x
eval (Bool x) = x
eval (Plus x y) = eval x + eval y
eval (If c t e) = if eval c then eval t else eval e
eval (Equal x y) = eval x == eval y
```

However, I struggle to implement an instance of `Eq` for the DSL. I tried the simple syntactic equality:

```
instance Eq a => Eq (Expr a) where
  Num x == Num y = x == y
  Bool x == Bool y = x == y
  Plus x y == Plus x' y' = x == x' && y == y'
  If c t e == If c' t' e' = c == c' && t == t' && e == e'
  Equal x y == Equal x' y' = x == x' && y == y'
  _ == _ = False
```

It does not typecheck (with `ghc 8.6.5`), the error is the following:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )

Main.hs:17:35: error:
    • Could not deduce: a2 ~ a1
      from the context: (a ~ Bool, Eq a1)
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
                   Equal :: forall a. Eq a => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool,
                 in an equation for ‘==’
        at Main.hs:17:3-11
      ‘a2’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a pattern with constructor:
          Equal :: forall a. Eq a => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool,
        in an equation for ‘==’
        at Main.hs:17:16-26
      ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a pattern with constructor:
          Equal :: forall a. Eq a => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool,
        in an equation for ‘==’
        at Main.hs:17:3-11
      Expected type: Expr a1
        Actual type: Expr a2
    • In the second argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘x'’
      In the first argument of ‘(&&)’, namely ‘x == x'’
      In the expression: x == x' && y == y'
    • Relevant bindings include
        y' :: Expr a2 (bound at Main.hs:17:25)
        x' :: Expr a2 (bound at Main.hs:17:22)
        y :: Expr a1 (bound at Main.hs:17:11)
        x :: Expr a1 (bound at Main.hs:17:9)
   |
17 |   Equal x y == Equal x' y' = x == x' && y == y'
   |
```

I believe the reason is that the constructor `Equal` "forgets" the value of the type parameter `a` of its subexpressions and there is no way for the typechecker to ensure subexpressions `x` and `y` both have the same type `Expr a`.

I tried adding one more type parameter to `Expr a` to keep track of the type of subexpressions:

```
data Expr a b where
  Num :: Int -> Expr Int b
  Bool :: Bool -> Expr Bool b
  Plus :: Expr Int b -> Expr Int b -> Expr Int b
  If :: Expr Bool b -> Expr a b -> Expr a b -> Expr a b
  Equal :: Eq a => Expr a a -> Expr a a -> Expr Bool a

instance Eq a => Eq (Expr a b) where
  -- same implementation

eval :: Expr a b -> a
  -- same implementation
```

This approach does not seem scalable to me, once more constructors with subexpressions of different types are added.

All this makes me think that I do use GADTs incorrectly to implement this kind of DSL. Is there a way to implement `Eq` for this type? If not, what is the idiomatic way to express this kind of type constraint on the expressions?

Complete code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
 
module Main where

data Expr a where
  Num :: Int -> Expr Int
  Bool :: Bool -> Expr Bool
  Plus :: Expr Int -> Expr Int -> Expr Int
  If :: Expr Bool -> Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr a
  Equal :: Eq a => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool

instance Eq a => Eq (Expr a) where
  Num x == Num y = x == y
  Bool x == Bool y = x == y
  Plus x y == Plus x' y' = x == x' && y == y'
  If c t e == If c' t' e' = c == c' && t == t' && e == e'
  Equal x y == Equal x' y' = x == x' && y == y'
  _ == _ = False

eval :: Expr a -> a
eval (Num x) = x
eval (Bool x) = x
eval (Plus x y) = eval x + eval y
eval (If c t e) = if eval c then eval t else eval e
eval (Equal x y) = eval x == eval y

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let expr1 = If (Equal (Num 13) (Num 42)) (Bool True) (Bool False)
  let expr2 = If (Equal (Num 13) (Num 42)) (Num 42) (Num 777)
  print (eval expr1)
  print (eval expr2)
  print (expr1 == expr1)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your issue is that in

```
Equal x y == Equal x' y' = ...
```

it is possible that `x` and `x'` have different types. For example, `Equal (Bool True) (Bool True) == Equal (Int 42) (Int 42)` type checks, but we can't then simply compare `Bool True == Int 42` as we might try to do in the `Eq` instance.

Here are a few alternative solutions. The last one (generalizing `==` to `eqExpr`) seems the simplest to me, but the others are interesting as well.

## Use a singleton and compute types

We start from your original type

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
module Main where

data Expr a where
  Num :: Int -> Expr Int
  Bool :: Bool -> Expr Bool
  Plus :: Expr Int -> Expr Int -> Expr Int
  If :: Expr Bool -> Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr a
  Equal :: Eq a => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool
```

and define a singleton GADT to represent the types you have

```
data Ty a where
  TyInt  :: Ty Int
  TyBool :: Ty Bool
```

We then prove that your types can only be `Int` or `Bool`, and how to compute them from the expression.

```
tyExpr :: Expr a -> Ty a
tyExpr (Num _)     = TyInt
tyExpr (Bool _)    = TyBool
tyExpr (Plus _ _)  = TyInt
tyExpr (If _ t _)  = tyExpr t
tyExpr (Equal _ _) = TyBool
```

We can now exploit that and define the `Eq` instance.

```
instance Eq (Expr a) where
  Num x     == Num y       = x == y
  Bool x    == Bool y      = x == y
  Plus x y  == Plus x' y'  = x == x' && y == y'
  If c t e  == If c' t' e' = c == c' && t == t' && e == e'
  Equal x y == Equal x' y' = case (tyExpr x, tyExpr x') of
     (TyInt,  TyInt ) -> x == x' && y == y'
     (TyBool, TyBool) -> x == x' && y == y'
     _                -> False
  _ == _ = False
```

## Use Typeable

We slightly modify the original GADT:

```
import Data.Typeable
  
data Expr a where
  Num :: Int -> Expr Int
  Bool :: Bool -> Expr Bool
  Plus :: Expr Int -> Expr Int -> Expr Int
  If :: Expr Bool -> Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr a
  Equal :: (Typeable a, Eq a) => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool
```

We can then try to cast the values to the right types: if the cast fails, we had two `Equal`s among distinct types, so we can return `False`.

```
instance Eq (Expr a) where
  Num x     == Num y       = x == y
  Bool x    == Bool y      = x == y
  Plus x y  == Plus x' y'  = x == x' && y == y'
  If c t e  == If c' t' e' = c == c' && t == t' && e == e'
  Equal x y == Equal x' y' = case cast (x,y) of
     Just (x2, y2) -> x2 == x' && y2 == y'
     Nothing       -> False
  _ == _ = False
```

## Generalize to heterogeneous equality

We can use the original GADT:

```
data Expr a where
  Num :: Int -> Expr Int
  Bool :: Bool -> Expr Bool
  Plus :: Expr Int -> Expr Int -> Expr Int
  If :: Expr Bool -> Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr a
  Equal :: Eq a => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool
```

and write a *heterogeneous* equality test, that can work even if the two expressions haven't the same type:

```
eqExpr :: Expr a -> Expr b -> Bool
eqExpr (Num x)     (Num y)       = x == y
eqExpr (Bool x)    (Bool y)      = x == y
eqExpr (Plus x y)  (Plus x' y')  = eqExpr x x' && eqExpr y y'
eqExpr (If c t e)  (If c' t' e') = eqExpr c c' && eqExpr t t' && eqExpr e e'
eqExpr (Equal x y) (Equal x' y') = eqExpr x x' && eqExpr y y'
eqExpr _           _             = False
```

The `Eq` instance is then a special case.

```
instance Eq (Expr a) where
  (==) = eqExpr
```

## A final note

As pointed out by Joseph Sible in the comments, in all these approaches we do not need the `Eq a` context in the instances. We can simply remove it:

```
instance {- Eq a => -} Eq (Expr a) where
   ...
```

Further, in principle we do not even really need the `Eq a` in the definition of `Equal`, so we could simplify our GADT:

```
data Expr a where
  Num :: Int -> Expr Int
  Bool :: Bool -> Expr Bool
  Plus :: Expr Int -> Expr Int -> Expr Int
  If :: Expr Bool -> Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr a
  Equal :: Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool
```

However, if we do that the definition of `eval :: Expr a -> a` becomes more complex in the `Equal` case, where we probably need to use something like `tyExpr` to infer the type, so that we can use `==`.

Comment: I was going to post an answer saying you could implement `Equal x y == Equal x' y'` by doing case analysis on x, y, x', and y', since that gets you knowledge of what the type parameters are. But implementing that as a general heterogenous equality function rather than burying the same code in one case of the Eq instance is much better than my idea.

Comment: This answer should be mandatory reading for anyone who says type checkers just get in their way. An excellent pragmatic example of using the type system to *prove* properties about your data types.

Comment: Do you need `instance Eq a => Eq (Expr a) where`? Can't it just be `instance Eq (Expr a) where`?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Right! We indeed do not need that. We also do not need the `Eq a` in the GADT.